# How can I create a one to many relationship that allows me to query two tables?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two models `Products` and `ProductImage`.

I've created a one to many relationship in the `Product` model as follows:

```
public function images()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ProductImage::class);
}
```

From my controller, I'm trying to retrieve all 'shown' products and their related images in the `product_images` table as follows:

```
$products = Product::find(1)->images()
  ->where('shown', 1)
  ->get();
```

There is a `shown` column in my `products` table but not in the `product_images` table so I'm getting this error:

```
  SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'shown' in
  'where clause' (SQL: select * from `product_images` where
  `product_images`.`product_id` = 1 and `product_images`.`product_id` is not
  null and `shown` = 1)
```

1. Why is the query trying to apply the where condition to the `product_images` table as opposed to the `products` table?
2. How can can I achieve the desired result of getting all products and their related images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do something like this

```
$products = Product::where('shown',1)->with('images')
->get();
```

This query will get the shown products and eager load the related images for each product

Answer (score 1):

$products = Product::where('shown',1)->with('product_images')
->get(); and column product_id mustbe in product_images table